# Unitary $T : V \to V$ preserves $W \le V$ and $W^\perp$.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V$ be an inner product space over $\mathbb{F}$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and $T : V \to V$ a unitary linear operator, i.e. $T \circ T^* = \mathrm{id} = T^* \circ T$, where $T^*$ is the adjoint of $T$. Suppose that $W \le V$ is a $T$-invariant subspace, that is $TW \subseteq W$. Show that the orthogonal complement $W^\perp$ is also $T$-invariant.

I have a solution for when $V$ is finite-dimensional, which I have posted as an answer below. However, I would be interested in knowing if the result also holds in infinite dimensions, and seeing a proof thereof. Alternative proofs for finite dimensions are also welcome, though I shan't accept them as answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in infinite dimension.  Take for example $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $T$ the left shift operator $T(f)(n)=f(n+1)$ and $V=\{f:f(n)=0\text{ for }n>0\}$.  Then $T$ is unitary, $V$ is $T$-invariant, but $V^\perp$ is not $T$-invariant.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: For some reason I did not see your answer post when I wrote my answer.  Some glitch on the site.

Comment: My answer was deleted because my first answer was wrong. So the current answer from me was not visible when you were answering.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t notice the $\mathbb Z.$ Sorry. Deleting comment.

Comment: Nice answer. I've accepted this one based on clarity, but I appreciated both your efforts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose further that $V$ is finite-dimensional and, without loss of generality, that $W \ne V$. Let $w \in W^\perp$ be non-zero and consider the sequence $(T^k w)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$. By finite-dimensionality, there exists a non-trivial linear dependence $$\sum_{k=0}^n \lambda_k T^k w = 0,$$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\lambda_k \in \mathbb{F}$. Since $w \ne 0$, we may choose $n > 0$ so that $\lambda_n \ne 0$. Then, by applying $(T^*)^{n-1}$ and rearranging the above, we find that $$\lambda_n Tw = -\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lambda_k (T^*)^{n-1-k} w.$$ But $W^\perp$ is $T^*$-invariant, so $(T^*)^k w \in W^\perp$ for all $k \ge 0$. Since $\lambda_n \ne 0$, we conclude that $Tw \in W^\perp$. Hence $W^\perp$ is $T$-invariant.

Comment: Since $T$ is invertible, the dimension of $TW$ and $W$ are the same, so $TW\subseteq W$ means $TW=W$ when in finite dimensions. So you can do the obvious proof.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Cheers. After you had posted your original (now deleted) answer, I also realised this would work. Nice and concise!